# Adding same objects into TableView more than once at different times

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I'm trying to build a project for shopping. This program can keep all added products in the SQLite database without any problem.

There are some constraints.

A product can be the main or standard product. Main products have its own sub-products. If the customer wants to buy the main product then the customer has to buy it's sub products as well.

Till now everything seems okay.In mainScreen I built 2 tableview on the top user can see a list of all products(tableProductsInfo) and below the table, you can see the shopping cart table (tableShoppingBasket).

If user selects a product from tableProductsInfo and click on *add to cart button*, this product will be added on the below and on shoppingBasket(observableList)  like in the picture.

Here My ADD To CART button codes

```
@FXML
public void addtoShoppingBasket() throws IOException {

    if(tableProductInfo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()!=null){ // eğer bir ürün seçiliyse // if any product selected?
        Product selectedItem = (Product) tableProductInfo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); //
        int inputQuantity = getInputDialogPane(); // Kaç tane ürün eklenmek istiyor? // how many products user wants to buy?
        if(selectedItem.getStock()>=inputQuantity){ // STOK KONTROL eğer eklenmek istenen ürün stokta varsa // Checking stock if its avaliable for selling
            selectedItem.setQuantity(inputQuantity);

            //main ürün şuan alınabilir durumda (sub ürünü varsa henüz değil)

            if (selectedItem.getSubProduct()==1){ // eğer sub ürünü varsa // if selected product has subProducts
                //that means its main product and we need to check its sub products

                //1)sub ürün listesini al, // get all subProducts of selectedItem
                //2) sub ürün stok kontrollerini yap main.Quantity*sub.Quantity <= Sub.stock // check its stock
                //3) eğer stokta varsa tabloya ekle yoksa uyarı ver // if any of subitems out of stock capasity then don't let user to buy the main product and its subProducts
                ProductDialogPaneController productDialogPaneController = new ProductDialogPaneController();
                ObservableList returnedList =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                returnedList=productDialogPaneController.getSubProducts(selectedItem.getProductID()); // getting all subproducts of main Product


                Iterator<Product> productIterator = returnedList.iterator();
                boolean inStock=true;
                while (productIterator.hasNext()){
                    Product currentSubProduct = productIterator.next();

                if((currentSubProduct.getQuantity()*selectedItem.getQuantity())>currentSubProduct.getStock()){
                    //eğer eklenmek istenen alt ürünün tanımlanan Miktarı*Alınmak istenen Main ürünün miktarı stok kapasitesinden fazla değilse
                    //sub products should multiply with main product quantity
                    inStock=false;
                }

                }
                if(inStock==true){
                    System.out.println("in stock true");

                    // there is no stock problem for any sub product
                    //here we need to check if shoppingBasket contains selected item or its sub products

                    //if it contains then update/change its quantity
                    //else then add selected item and its subProducts into shoppingBasket






                    shoppingBasket.add(selectedItem);
                    shoppingBasket.addAll(returnedList);

                }else{
                    System.out.println("ALMAK İSTEDİĞİNİZ MAİN ÜRÜNLE BİRLİKTE ALINMASI GEREKEN ALT ÜRÜNLERDEN BİRİ VEYA BİRKAÇI STOKTA YOK!");
                }



            }else{ //eğer sub ürünü yoksa (selectedItem.getSubProduct==0)
                //if it's not the main product in another words if its standard Product

                shoppingBasket.add(selectedItem);

            }

        }else{
            System.out.println("ALMAK İSTEDİĞİNİZ MAİN ÜRÜN STOKTA YETERİ KADAR YOK");
            //the product you wanted to buy is out of stock capacity
        }




    }else{ // eğer ürün listesinden bir ürün seçilmediyse
        System.out.println("ALIŞ VERİŞ SEPETİNE EKLENECEK ÜRÜNÜ SEÇMEDİNİZ !");
        //no item selected to buy
    }

}
```

I set my product items into shopping table like this;

```
@FXML
public void initialize(){
tableShoppingBasket.setItems(shoppingBasket);
}
```

**MY PROBLEM**

When tableShoppingBasket is clear;

If I wanted to add the MAIN Product **FIRST TIME**!
There is no problem seems.
You can see the main Screen here:
[image]

But when I wanted to add the same product **SECOND TIME**
There is a problem and my table seems like that

I don't want to list same products in different rows.

I want to update its quantity if this product added before.(oldProduct.getQuantity+newProduct.getQuantity)

I NEED TO FIX THIS VIEW:

[image]

**I wanted to update its quantity and see the table rows like this**

Label  Name   Price  Quantity

- Main mProduct 200 2
- Sub ProductX 10 2
- Sub Producty 50 2

I tried to fix my problem with this codes but it didn't worked as I wanted.
I mean it didn't add sub products of selected main product.

```
  //checking for MAIN PRODUCT
                    if(shoppingBasket.contains(selectedItem)){

                     int index= shoppingBasket.indexOf(selectedItem);
                        Product existingItem=shoppingBasket.get(index);
                        shoppingBasket.remove(selectedItem); //removing old item
                        existingItem.setQuantity(existingItem.getQuantity()+inputQuantity);
                     shoppingBasket.add(index,existingItem); // adding updated item
                    }else{
                        shoppingBasket.add(selectedItem); // if if its adding first time
                    }

                    //Checking for Sub Products



                    Iterator subItemIterator=returnedList.iterator();
                    while (subItemIterator.hasNext()){
                        Product newSubItem = (Product) subItemIterator.next();
                        Iterator ShoppingIterator = shoppingBasket.iterator();
                        if(shoppingBasket!=null && !shoppingBasket.isEmpty()){
                        while (ShoppingIterator.hasNext()){
                            Product oldSubItem= (Product) ShoppingIterator.next();
                            if(oldSubItem.getProductID()==newSubItem.getProductID()){
                                oldSubItem.setQuantity(newSubItem.getQuantity()+oldSubItem.getQuantity());
                            }else{
                                shoppingBasket.add(newSubItem);
                            }
                        }
                        } else {shoppingBasket.add(newSubItem);
                                                        }
                    }
```

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you're asking. What is the exact problem? Linking to an outside screenshot does not indicate what the problem is. On a side note, please do not post links to external screenshots; embed the image in your post, if necessary.

Comment: You can see my problem where I styled my text as **bold**. But let me make it clear again. I want to update shopping tableview when user add same product into  shopping cart at different time

Comment: “I tried to update products quantity on shoppingBasket(observableList) like this but it didnt work as i wanted.”  That code looks (mostly) correct to me.  What does “didn’t work as I wanted” mean?  What exactly was the result of that code?

Comment: @EmreSERBEST - That does not make it clear. You need to assume we know nothing about your application or how you want it to work (because we have no idea)...

Comment: Seems like you need to do something like. `if(checkouttable.contains(item){//Increment item quanity}else{//add new Item}`.

Comment: @Sedrick yes you are right I should do that but I couldn't till now. You can check what I tried and maybe you can help me. I edited my first message.

Comment: @VGR I edited my codes and tried something different and I faced with an error. You can check my sample codes to find out with this problem.

Comment: @Zephyr I edited my first message and tried to make it clear as much as I can...

Comment: Why are you removing the old products? Why not just increment their quality?

Comment: @Sedrick I tried without removing, It didn't change and I thought maybe Observable list doesn't realize this change. Both ways didn't work.

Comment: You are going to have to create a smaller version of your app with only the functions that are giving you your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved my problem.I found my some mistakes and you can find my running codes if you like.

**One of biggest my mistake**

```
shoppingBasket.contains(selectedItem);
```

Doesn't returns correct item if it's quantities are different.

I've solved my this problem by using iterator on shoppingBasket and comparing product ID's

@FXML
public void addtoShoppingBasket() throws IOException {

```
    if(tableProductInfo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()!=null){ // eğer bir ürün seçiliyse // if any product selected?
        Product selectedItem = (Product) tableProductInfo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); //
        int inputQuantity = getInputDialogPane(); // Kaç tane ürün eklenmek istiyor? // how many products user wants to buy?
        int totalQ=returnTotalQuantity(selectedItem); // if this item added already in the shopping basket we are subsraction added quantity

        if(selectedItem.getStock()-totalQ>=inputQuantity){ // STOK KONTROL eğer eklenmek istenen ürün stokta varsa // Checking stock if its avaliable for selling
            //selectedItem.setQuantity(inputQuantity);

            if (selectedItem.getSubProduct()==1){ // eğer sub ürünü varsa // if selected product has subProducts
                //that means its main product and we need to check its sub products

                //1)sub ürün listesini al, // get all subProducts of selectedItem
                //2) sub ürün stok kontrollerini yap main.Quantity*sub.Quantity <= Sub.stock // check its stock
                //3) eğer stokta varsa tabloya ekle yoksa uyarı ver // if any of subitems out of stock capasity then don't let user to buy the main product and its subProducts
                ProductDialogPaneController productDialogPaneController = new ProductDialogPaneController();
                ObservableList returnedList =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                returnedList=productDialogPaneController.getSubProducts(selectedItem.getProductID()); // getting all subproducts of main Product


                Iterator<Product> productIterator = returnedList.iterator();
                boolean inStock=true;
                while (productIterator.hasNext()){
                    Product currentSubProduct = productIterator.next();
                    int totalSubQ=returnTotalQuantity(currentSubProduct);
                if((currentSubProduct.getQuantity()*inputQuantity)>currentSubProduct.getStock()-totalSubQ){
                    //eğer eklenmek istenen alt ürünün tanımlanan Miktarı*Alınmak istenen Main ürünün miktarı stok kapasitesinden fazla değilse
                    //sub products should multiply with main product quantity
                    inStock=false;
                }

                }
                if(inStock==true){
                    if(shoppingBasket!=null && !shoppingBasket.isEmpty()){
                    Iterator mainIterator=shoppingBasket.iterator();
                    while (mainIterator.hasNext()){
                        Product oldMain= (Product) mainIterator.next();
                        if(oldMain.getProductID()==selectedItem.getProductID()){
                            oldMain.setQuantity(oldMain.getQuantity()+inputQuantity);
                        }
                    }
                        Iterator subItemIterator=returnedList.iterator();
                    while (subItemIterator.hasNext()){
                        Product newSubItem = (Product) subItemIterator.next();
                        Iterator ShoppingIterator = shoppingBasket.iterator();
                        while (ShoppingIterator.hasNext()){
                            Product oldSubItem= (Product) ShoppingIterator.next();
                            if(oldSubItem.getProductID()==newSubItem.getProductID() && oldSubItem.getSubProduct()!=1){
                                oldSubItem.setQuantity((newSubItem.getQuantity()*inputQuantity)+oldSubItem.getQuantity());
                                calculateTotalPriceofShoppingBasket();
                            }
                        }
                        }
                            }else{
                        selectedItem.setQuantity(inputQuantity);
                        shoppingBasket.add(selectedItem);
                        // we should multiply subItem Quantity with new InputQuantity
                       Iterator iterator = returnedList.iterator();
                       while (iterator.hasNext()){
                           Product newQforSubItem= (Product) iterator.next();
                           newQforSubItem.setQuantity(inputQuantity*newQforSubItem.getQuantity());
                       }
                        shoppingBasket.addAll(returnedList);
                    }

                }else{
                    System.out.println("ALMAK İSTEDİĞİNİZ MAİN ÜRÜNLE BİRLİKTE ALINMASI GEREKEN ALT ÜRÜNLERDEN BİRİ VEYA BİRKAÇI STOKTA YOK!");
                            //one of sub product out of its stock capacity
                }
            }else{ //eğer sub ürünü yoksa (selectedItem.getSubProduct==0)
                //if its not main product in other word if its standart Product
                selectedItem.setQuantity(inputQuantity);
                Iterator standartProduct = shoppingBasket.iterator();
                if(!shoppingBasket.isEmpty()&&shoppingBasket!=null) {
                    while (standartProduct.hasNext()) {
                        Product standart = (Product) standartProduct.next();
                        if (standart.getProductID() == selectedItem.getProductID()) {
                            standart.setQuantity(standart.getQuantity() + inputQuantity);
                            calculateTotalPriceofShoppingBasket();
                        }
                    }
                }else { // shoppingbasket is empty
                    selectedItem.setQuantity(inputQuantity);
                    shoppingBasket.add(selectedItem);
                }
            }

        }else{
            System.out.println("ALMAK İSTEDİĞİNİZ MAİN ÜRÜN STOKTA YETERİ KADAR YOK");
            //the product you wanted to buy is out of stock capacity
        }




    }else{ // eğer ürün listesinden bir ürün seçilmediyse
        System.out.println("ALIŞ VERİŞ SEPETİNE EKLENECEK ÜRÜNÜ SEÇMEDİNİZ !");
        //no item selected to buy
    }
```

}

Comment: You could always create your own `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods in your `Product` class to compare IDs instead of using a loop. Then the `contains()` method can still be used.